# take photo Using the storyboard or Xib in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to take a photo with Stroyboard (because I don't have iPhone )

know I have code Take photo and the select

and  then

What's the easiest way to resize/optimize an image size with the in iPhone

.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface APPViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)takePhoto:  (UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

.M

```
#import "APPViewController.h"

@interface APPViewController ()

@end

@implementation APPViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

@end
```

Comment: u need to take the photo from simulator, if u need to take the photo u   should need the device, u cant take the photo from the simulator

Comment: thk for answer @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the Camera is available or not for that using **UIImagePickerController** of

> `+ (BOOL)isSourceTypeAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType;`

For your scenario  you should write **takePhoto** method like that :

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            //Do your stuff here
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message: @"Camera is not available." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];      
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Using Simulator you can't take photo. You must require device from take photo or open camera.

may it will help you.

Happy coding...:)

Comment: thk for answer and open camera with Stroyboard it's possible or Not plz help me

Comment: take photo you must have the device require.if device haven't camera available then it's give you alert from above code.

Comment: With storyboard or simulator it's impossible to take photos.that's at.

Comment: thk for answering but my code is not open camera when click takePhoto button jest display the camera is not available plz help me how to take photos with Storyboard

Comment: that's why i am telling you put there condition if available camera then don't worry if not then display user alert .

Comment: with storyboard/Simulator is not possible to take photo or open camera .